# How to point Karma unit test cases to hit the services host on 8085 port instead of 9876

Tags: apache, angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I need to run test cases in Karma Jasmine which should hit services hosted on 8085 port by Apache. However, Karma is hitting those services at port#9876 and thus, giving 404 error.

I tried to set the port in Karma configuration file as 8085, but it said that the port is already being used by some other application.

Checked multiple place, but of no help.

Any quick help to get me through this is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: what url do you want to access on 8085?

Comment: I want the Karma to hit an AJAX service call used in the project to fetch data - example: localhost:8085/getData

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [proxies option](http://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html):

> Description: A map of path-proxy pairs.

```
proxies: {
  '/getData': 'http://localhost:8085/getData'
```